# Read from array one by one - VBScript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am trying to read from a file, create an array, then write to a second file line by line (element by element) while adding some additional information.  The script below will read correctly from a file, but will only write the last line in the initial file. How can I write from the array one at a time? (I can write the contents to the second file in a different manner, but I want to do it directly from the array).

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(input, 
ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    arrFields = Split(strLine, ",")
    If InStr(arrFields(1), "False") Then
        strContents = strContents & arrFields(0) & vbCrlf
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(output)

' below correctly outputs contents
' objFile.Write strContents 

For each i in arrFields
    objFile.Write arrFields(0)
    objFile.Write "Number" & vbCrlf
Next

objFile.Close
```

My test csv file reads as below saved as "test.csv" from notepad.

```
1,FALSE
2,FALSE
3,FALSE
4,FALSE
5,FALSE
6,FALSE
7,FALSE
8,FALSE
9,FALSE
10,FALSE
11,FALSE
12,FALSE
13,TRUE
```

Comment: Shouldn't you write `i` instead of `arrFields(0)` in `For Each` Loop?

Comment: I thought so, but I get an error saying subscript i is out of range. I don't really know what that means.

Comment: I am not sure what extra info you are adding from File 1 to File 2. It looks like you are simply reading one file and trying to write the same in File 2. Can you be more specific as to what processing you want to do before writing stuff in File 2?

Comment: I am just new and trying to learn. I don't really want to process the data in any specific way.  The only addition is the word "number" after the first column of data. (Input file is a csv with two columns "1, false" etc. I want an output file with two columns "1 number")

Comment: Try the sample code - hope you want something similar

Comment: For whatever reason the output file still gives me only the last line in the original file.

Comment: Can you share your csv? Is it unix or windows file?

Comment: Windows. The file contents are below saved from notepad as "test.csv"

1,FALSE
2,FALSE
3,FALSE
4,FALSE
5,FALSE
6,FALSE
7,FALSE
8,FALSE
9,FALSE
10,FALSE
11,FALSE
12,FALSE
13,TRUE

Comment: Open in notepad++ and check how the lines are terminated. Is it CrLf or just Cr?

Comment: It terminates with CrLf

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem as the sample code works on a csv. Maybe you can share the sample file?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.csv", ForReading)

arrFields = Split(objFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test1.txt")
For i = LBound(arrFields) To UBound(arrFields)
    objFile.Write "Number " & i+1 & "," & Split(arrFields(i),",")(0) & vbCrlf
Next
objFile.Close
```